My Samsung A51 locked for 24 hrs
My Samsung A 51 got locked for 24 hrs as I was using it with finger print but my little kid did multiple attempts on pattern, now I am doing attempt every after 24 hrs, I know there is no possible way to get into my phone and I don't want to erase my all data. Having a lot of memories of my family. My question is that how long can I do attempts or it will block the phone forever?
